# How to identify disabled radio buttons using Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

While recording the script using Selenium IDE,I'm able to record Enabled "ON/"FF" radio buttons. However , when I want to check the Disabled Radio Buttons, it is not showing invidual ID for ON or OFF buttons. It shows only a single ID for both the Buttons in Disabled state. How would I get their status or ID individually when they are disabled..??

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath to check if the disabled attribute is set properly. Use this as your target and replace id-Attribute with the name-attribute if needed and the content of the value-attribute. If no disabled-attribute exists, Selenium will display an error.

Xpath:

```
//input[@id='a' and @value='2']/@disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try **verifyElementValue** command :)
or **storeElementValue** and then match result.
you can see more information about this commands in Selenium